# PHP form to Email - Email to contain data only from the filled out fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a form that uses jQuery (to hide and show form options) and PHP the process the form and send the values to email. The jQuery is working fine and the PHP is sending the email successfully. However, I only want the options that are chosen to be included in the email.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


$email_to = "sales@email.net";
$email_subject = "Enquiry";
$thankyou_url = "http://www.url.com";

  function died($error) {

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['address']) ||
    !isset($_POST['address2']) ||
    !isset($_POST['address3']) ||
    !isset($_POST['postcode']) ||
    !isset($_POST['tel']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['design']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype2']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font2']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype3']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font3']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype4']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font4']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype5']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font5']) ||
    !isset($_POST['woodtype6']) ||
    !isset($_POST['font6']) ||

    !isset($_POST['line1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['line2']) ||
    !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$address = $_POST['address']; // not required
$address2 = $_POST['address2']; // not required
$address3 = $_POST['address3']; // not required
$postcode = $_POST['postcode']; // not required
$tel = $_POST['tel']; // not required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$design = $_POST['design']; // not required
$woodtype = $_POST['woodtype']; // not required
$font = $_POST['font']; // not required
$woodtype2 = $_POST['woodtype2']; // not required
$font2 = $_POST['font2']; // not required
$woodtype3 = $_POST['woodtype3']; // not required
$font3 = $_POST['font3']; // not required
$woodtype4 = $_POST['woodtype4']; // not required
$font4 = $_POST['font4']; // not required
$woodtype5 = $_POST['woodtype5']; // not required
$font5 = $_POST['font5']; // not required
$woodtype6 = $_POST['woodtype6']; // not required
$font6 = $_POST['font6']; // not required

$line1 = $_POST['line1']; // required
$line2 = $_POST['line2']; // not required
$message = $_POST['message']; // not required


$error_message = "";



$email_message = "New Order\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";                      
$email_message .= "Address2: ".clean_string($address2)."\n";
$email_message .= "Address3: ".clean_string($address3)."\n";
$email_message .= "Postcode: ".clean_string($postcode)."\n";
$email_message .= "Tel: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";                      
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Design: ".clean_string($design)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype2)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font2)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype3)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font3)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype4)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font4)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype5)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font5)."\n";
$email_message .= "Woodtype: ".clean_string($woodtype6)."\n";
$email_message .= "Font: ".clean_string($font6)."\n";

$email_message .= "Line1: ".clean_string($line1)."\n";
$email_message .= "Line2: ".clean_string($line2)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


header("Location: http://www.url.com");
} else {
echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
}
?>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design A" ) {

            $("#hide1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide1").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });

    $("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design B" ) {

            $("#hide2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });


$("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design C" ) {

            $("#hide3").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide3").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });

    $("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design D" ) {

            $("#hide4").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide4").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });

    $("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design E" ) {

            $("#hide5").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide5").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });

    $("#select1").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Design F" ) {

            $("#hide6").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

        } else {

            $("#hide6").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

        }
    });
});


</script>
```

And finally the HTML is:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="sendform.php" method="post" name="contact_form" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for your order, we will be in touch shortly. You will now be redirected to the homepage.');">
        <fieldset style="padding:10px; margin:0 auto; width:939px; padding:10px; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); border-radius:10px;">
          <legend style="background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#DDD)); border-radius:5px; padding:5px; border:#6C6C6C 2px solid;">Customer Details</legend>
          <br />
          <br />
          <ul>
            <li> <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span> </li>
            <li>
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="John Doe" required />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="address">Address: <br />
                (Required for delivery)</label>
              <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="The Willows" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="address2"></label>
              <input type="text" name="address2"  placeholder="Romsey Road" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="address3"></label>
              <input type="text" name="address3" placeholder="East Wellow" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
              <input type="text" name="postcode"  placeholder="SO51 6BG" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="tel">Telephone:</label>
              <input type="tel" name="tel" required="required" placeholder="02380 123456" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com"/>
              <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span> </li>
          </ul><br /><br />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <br />
        <fieldset style="padding:5px; width:939px;
padding:10px; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#EEE)); border-radius:10px;">
          <legend style="background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#DDD)); border-radius:5px; padding:5px; border:#6C6C6C 2px solid;">Sign Details</legend>

          <ul>
          <li style="border:none;">
          <div class="input select">
        <label for="select1">Choose a Design</label>
        <select name="design" id="select1">
            <option value="default">Select Design</option>
            <option value="Design A">Design A</option>
            <option value="Design B">Design B</option>
            <option value="Design C">Design C</option>
            <option value="Design D">Design D</option>
            <option value="Design E">Design E</option>
            <option value="Design F">Design F</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
    <div class="hide" id="hide1">
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select1">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype" id="select1">
                <option value="">Select Wood</option>
                <option value="Oak">Oak</option>
                <option value="Mahogany">Mahogany</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select1">Font:</label>
            <select name="font" id="select1">
                <option value="">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Century (Default)">Century (Default)</option>
                <option value="Roman">Roman</option>
                <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                <option value="Old English">Old English</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
    <div class="hide" id="hide2"> 
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select2">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype2" id="select2">
                <option value="">Select Wood</option>
                <option value="Oak">Oak</option>
                <option value="Mahogany">Mahogany</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select2">Font:</label>
            <select name="font2" id="select2">
                <option value="">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Roman (Default)">Roman (Default)</option>
                <option value="Century">Century</option>
                <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                <option value="Old English">Old English</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      </li>

        <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
    <div class="hide" id="hide3">
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select3">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype3" id="select3">
                <option value="default">Select Wood</option>
                <option value="Birch Only">Birch Only</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select3">Font:</label>
            <select name="font3" id="select3">
                <option value="default">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Old English (Default)">Old English (Default)</option>
                <option value="Century">Century</option>
                <option value="Roman">Roman</option>
                <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      </li>

       <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
      <div class="hide" id="hide4"> 
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select4">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype4" id="select4">
                <option value="default">Wood</option>
                <option value="Oak">Oak</option>
                <option value="Mahogany">Mahogany</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select4">Font:</label>
            <select name="font4" id="select4">
                <option value="default">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Helvetica (Default)">Helvetica (Default)</option>
                <option value="Century">Century</option>
                <option value="Roman">Roman</option>
                <option value="Old English">Old English</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      </li>

       <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
      <div class="hide" id="hide5"> 
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select5">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype5" id="select5">
                <option value="default">Select Wood</option>
                <option value="Birch Only">Birch Only</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select5">Font:</label>
            <select name="font5" id="select5">
                <option value="default">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Times New Roman Numerals">Times New Roman Numerals</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      </li>

       <li style="border:none; padding:0;">
      <div class="hide" id="hide6"> 
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select6">Wood Type:</label>
            <select name="woodtype6" id="select6">
                <option value="default">Wood</option>
                <option value="Oak">Oak</option>
                <option value="Mahogany">Mahogany</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="select6">Select Font:</label>
            <select name="font6" id="select6">
                <option value="default">Choose A Font</option>
                <option value="Times New Roman Numerals">Times New Roman Numerals</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      </li>
            <li>
              <label for="line1">Line 1:</label>
              <textarea name="line1" cols="40" rows="1" placeholder="The Willows" required ></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="line2">Line 2:</label>
              <textarea name="line2" cols="40" rows="1" ></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="message">Specific Requirements:</label>
              <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" placeholder="All uppercase."></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button class="submit" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer; padding:5px;">Submit Order</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

I am a novice with PHP and jQuery (Ive had a bit more experience using HTML and CSS) so please let me know if there are any mistakes or there is an easier solution for something!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You said the jQuery and PHP parts are fine.  The email part is what you need help with.  So please take out all the code that is not directly related to the problem at hand.  Short concise questions get answers.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey apologies, I am new to this site and am not sure what information people would require to help solve this. What code shall I take out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this for each variable;
 `if(isset($address) && $address){

    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";

  }`

This makes sure the value is set and not null /blank before adding it to your email.

A slightly more advanced solution would be to create an array of the optional post vars and loop over that array checking for each value to compile your email.

Comment: Thanks, I have adapted it to each of the variables that require it and some of them get excluded form the email but there are still a couple showing...this is the email i receive:     New Order

Name: Bla
Address: bla
Address2: bla
Address3: bla
Postcode: bla
Tel: 80948908
Email: bla@bla.co.uk
Design: Design C
Woodtype: Birch Only
Font: Old English (Default)
Woodtype: default
Font: default
Woodtype: default
Font: default
Woodtype: default
Font: default
Line1: Bla
Line2: 
Message: Max 40" long

Comment: when you say "there are still a couple showing" are you talking about those with "default" values?  If so, I would change in your form (for example) `<option value="default">Choose A Font</option>` to `<option value="">Choose A Font</option>`

Comment: Thats worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. Legend. This is why I refer to this site when I have a problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden form fields to track dirty vs. clean input fields, and validate against those in PHP. For example, if there is a group of fields contained in a section called "My Info," then check the value of a hidden field called "use_my_info" to see if you should process those fields or not. It should be a simple addition to your application logic, and you'll just need to add a few hidden fields.

Cheers